# How can I save a key value from external API in django models?

Tags: python, django

My idea is that I want to create sort of save/like button in my app.

In my services.py and views.py I call and display the API data and
the API result looks like that

```
[
    {'rating':4,
     'name': 'Whatever name there is',
     'id': 'whatever ID there is',
    }
]
```

is there a way to save an ID part to my models and how can I implement this? considering that each time I use api, the API result might change.

Comment: could you elaborate on the requirement

Comment: @rajkris I get a JSON result and from that result I want to save it to my models.py(not sure if that even possible) so for instance, i get some result and from that result I want to take a value of a key i.e ['key':value] and save the value for example SomeModel.py as an instance.
The JSON result comes from views.py and displayed in templates tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify how the model and view look like, but I will improvise

models.py

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  extra_id = models.InetgerField()
  raiting = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
from app.models import SomeModel

def save_json(request):
  the_json = {
     'rating':4,
     'name': 'Whatever name there is',
     'id': 'whatever ID there is',
  }

  some_model = SomeModel.objects.create(
    extra_id=int(the_json['id']),
    name=the_json['name'],
    raiting=int(the_json['raiting'])
  )

  # and later if you want make operation on model.
  some_model = SomeModel.objects.get(extra_id=759)
  # for example...
  some_model.raiting = 4 
  some_model.save()
```

Comment: the whole Views.py were not necessary haha , but thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for ! i just wasnt quite sure if I can create table/model on the go, thanks !